# Como deixar claro que uma questão não é uma "duplicada"?

Tags: debate, suporte, perguntas-duplicadas

A questão [Alternativas para pagamentos de bens ou serviços com cartão de crédito no iOS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14444/alternativas-para-pagamentos-de-bens-ou-servicos-com-cartao-de-credito-no-ios) foi fechada como duplicada, mas por uma má interpretação da questão. Já realizei algumas edições para reabertura, mas parece não ter surtido efeito, pois a primeira vista ainda parece ser uma pergunta duplicada. O que é sugerido nesse caso?

Comment: Eu por exemplo votei como off-topic, mas a maioria votou como duplicado. Isso é uma coisa chata do nosso *engine*. Parece que eu que fiz a besteira. É off porque este é um site de Q&A e não um catálogo de fornecedores.

Comment: @bigown concordo com você, e acho que isso é algo que poderia ser mudado, talvez o certo seria fechar a questão quando houvessem 5 votos em determinado motivo, e não no total, ou informar quem votou no que.

Comment: Eu votei como off-topic. Pra mim claramente não era duplicata, mas infelizmente não dá pra transformar o SOpt num catálogo de prestadores de serviço. Sei que é um problema real, mas fora do escopo. Ou jajá pergunto quem vende impressora fiscal lá, que dá no mesmo (e viramos o novo search engine de prestadores de serviço e fornecedores de TI)

Comment: Sou a favor de mostrar o motivo individualizado. Acho que isso é assunto pro big meta (se é que não foi discutido ainda).

Answer (score 4):

### Sobre a pergunta do SOpt que foi mencionada:

**Ela não é duplicada. É off topic.**

Inclusive eu e o @bigown votamos desta forma, pelo que deu pra notar nos comments.

De fato, assim que li, e vi o link de referência nos respectivos comments, vi que os problemas eram completamente diferentes, e que o OP sabia claramente que no caso dele seria uma venda fora do app, permitida (portanto não coberta pela outra pergunta).

No entanto, entendo que isto é matéria de pesquisa nos search engines, assim como alguém "procurando uma impressora fiscal com porta USB, pois a lib que usa não dá suporte à serial", fica no mesmo patamar.

Em outras palavras: é um problema que o programador precisa resolver, mas **não é um problema de programação**. Tudo bem que perguntas sobre ferramentas de programação e coisas relacionadas com OS acabaram sendo adotadas pela comunidade, mas acho que tem um limite subjetivo, e não tão bem definido, e certas questões ficam "flutuando" em cima deste limite. Essa, no caso, acho que já passou um pouquinho a mais dessa "linha borrada".

**A reabertura é correta**, mas apenas para fechar do jeito certo, no meu entendimento.

> Gostaria de votar novamente para fechar como *off-topic*, mas vou esperar um momento para ter feedback e opiniões do resto da comunidade.

Comment: Concordo com você, mas a pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13538/tipos-de-pagamento-proibidos-no-ios não seria também um off-topic? Acho ela até pior, pois remete a uma dúvida que está ainda mais distante de uma questão de programação. Está mais para suporte da Apple.

Comment: @PauloMaciel pra falar a verdade aquela eu também achei, mas tenho tentado adotar uma postura um pouco mais tolerante. Ainda mais com resposta aceita, aí acaa caindo naquela "tolerância extra". Por outro lado, essa que estamos discutindo pra mim já é "demais off" pra fazer vista grossa. Mas se for olhar friamente, concordo que as duas tem problemas. :) –

Comment: Ainda acho a outra pior "Tipos de pagamento proibidos no IOS", não tem nada haver com programação, é mais uma dúvida sobre a plataforma da Apple. Por mim fecharia todas, mesmo com resposta aceita, ele deveria publicar essa pergunta no forum da Apple.

Comment: @PauloMaciel Eu acho perfeitamente válida sua afirmação. Vou aguardar um pouco a opinião das pessoas, para somar ao meu juízo de valor, depois eventualmente votar pra fechar.

Comment: @Bacco fui eu quem postou a pergunta, e pela minha experiência no SO eu já sabia que poderia ser off-topic. Mas infelizmente, não existe (ou não conheço) uma comunidade forte de desenvolvedores iOS aqui no Brasil onde eu pudesse achar a resposta para a pergunta. Infelizmente, ela também não pode ser respondida pela comunidade internacional porque é muito particular do nosso país. Sei que não é o ideal, mas veja que mesmo fora de contexto, já teve 4 votos em algumas horas, ou seja, há uma certa relevância.

Comment: @Guilherme eu entendo, e tenho certeza que é uma dúvida válida no dia-a-dia de várias pessoas. O problema é só o fato de fugir da proposta do site, o que abre um precedente complicado (diria que de certa forma outras perguntas de outras pessoas até já abriram exceção demais pro meu gosto). Não ache que é pessoal, e se eu soubesse a resposta, poria num comment (não no lugar da resposta, senão estaria endossando a pergunta). Realmente espero que você encontre uma solução, mas continuo achando que esse não seria o lugar apropriado. De qq forma, importante você participar com seus argumentos!

Comment: Concordo Bacco, o SOPT em algumas coisas está a ficar uma bagunça, quase todas as perguntas levam UPVOTE, estejam bem redigidas ou não, dentro ou fora do escopo, o que interessa é upar a pergunta... bah.

Answer (score 2):

1. Comente e edite o quanto for necessário, de modo a ficar claro que se trata de uma pergunta diferente;
2. Vote pela reabertura;
3. Se ela não for reaberta em algumas horas (às vezes demora um pouco pras pessoas acessarem a [fila de análise](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen)), traga a questão pro meta.

Se achar necessário, você pode discuti-la no meta antes desse período de espera (por exemplo, se houver dúvidas, e você achar que um feedback da comunidade é necessário). Mas em geral, não há necessidade - a pergunta ficará na fila de análise por pelo menos uns dias, de modo que eventualmente será vista. Somente se os avaliadores não concordarem que não se trata de uma duplicata, é que a reabertura será rejeitada.

Caso contrário, faça pelo menos os passos 1 e 2 **nessa ordem**: como o voto pela reabertura foi dado *antes* da edição, [ela acabou por ser rejeitada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/8728). Ainda é possível reabri-la, mas ela já não está mais na fila de análise (que eu saiba). Também é possível que os demais analisadores encontraram outro(s) problema(s) com a pergunta, e preferiram deixá-la fechada (i.e. por outro motivo). Um comentário a respeito seria bem-vindo, mas nem sempre isso acontece (como já está fechada mesmo, que importa se o motivo de fechamento é outro...).

Comment: A pergunta basicamente é "Gostaria de saber que outras empresas fazem esse tipo de serviço no Brasil, de preferência que tenham um SDK para o iOS e que não precise acessar uma página web para realizar a transação". Os requisitos são mais ou menos precisos, mas não sei se é papel do site esse tipo de recomendação. Votei pela reabertura, com um pé atrás, para ver no que dá.

Comment: @bfavaretto É, também fiquei meio na dúvida. Daí meu esclarecimento no final (quem votou pra manter fechada, pode ter votado por outros motivos, e não por ser duplicata).

Comment: O problema foi que a pergunta foi fechada por ter sido analisada como "pergunta duplicada", o que não é o caso, já em relação ao mérito da pergunta, tenho minhas dúvidas também, apesar de ser relevante para quem está desenvolvendo este tipo de recurso de pagamento.

Comment: Eu tinha duvidas se podia discutir essas questões no meta, mas você já respondeu no 3.

Comment: @PauloMaciel É, pode sim. Acho que tem até uma tag "pergunta-específica" ou algo assim (quando o debate é sobre um caso específico, e não sobre o caso geral) - bem como "resposta-específica" e "tag-específica", talvez outras.

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu votei como off-topic.

Comment: Concordo, está fechada, é o que importa, se por isto ou aquilo, eu acho que devia estar fechada, não vou votar para reabrir só para fechar de novo.

Answer (score 0):

Na minha opinião ela não é duplicada nem foge do escopo de programação, acho uma pergunta muito interessante e pertinente na vida dos programadores. Entretanto é possível que ela se enquadre como **principalmente baseada em opiniões**, pois as respostas basicamente são uma lista de possíveis soluções.

Listas não são bem vindas no SOPT por motivos amplamente já discutidos aqui, caso você os desconheça posso procurar alguns links para embasar essa informação.

Minha sugestão é: se você perceber que a respostas que estão surgindo basicamente te dão uma lista de opções, tente tornar sua pergunta mais objetiva e específica, entretanto não sei se ainda é possível contornar esse problema para a pergunta em questão, talvez fosse o caso de você deixar ela ser fechada, ir em busca de possíveis soluções, e ao se deparar com um problema dentro de uma ferramenta específica você abrir uma nova pergunta sobre as dificuldades técnicas encontradas.

Comment: Math estás só a pensar na comunidade Brasileira, e o resto da comunidade isso serve para que? Imagina no SOEN eu a perguntar se conhecem alguma empresa em Portugal, era logo fechada...

Comment: @JorgeB. desculpa, mas não entendi seu comentário. Eu disse que sou a favor de fechar a pergunta por ser baseada em opiniões, apesar de eu me interessar pelas possíveis respostas. Não acho que seja descontextualizada pois trata de dificuldades de programação, e a solução serve tanto para brasileiros, como portugueses como para pessoas de qualquer país. Poderia esclarecer o que você quis dizer?

Comment: Math esse tipo de serviço não é igual em pais nenhum do mundo as transações aqui são diferentes dai. Se houver por acaso uma empresa ai que tenha um SDK para transações, ele não vai funcionar em mais lado nenhum, só no Brasil. Por isso é que acho descontextualizada, porque só faz parte do contexto Brasil. Não servirá de nada aos restantes utilizadores, na minha opinião.

Comment: @JorgeB. talvez seja o caso de servir só para o Brasil, não sei, supondo que seja vc diria que ela é descontextualizada por isso? Eu diria que não. Se eu fizer uma pergunta de Java, ela não vai servir para C#, isso não faz dela descontextualizada, por que que no caso de servir para um país e não servir para outros seria? Ainda acho que ela _pode_ ser fechada por ser considerada uma lista.

Comment: Eu também acho que sim Math. Mas a meu ver também é descontextualizada por isso, imagina a mesma pergunta no SOEN, não seria fechada como descontextualizada?

Comment: @JorgeB. não devemos nos prender muito ao SOEN, podemos usá-los como baliza para tomarmos determinadas decisões. Respondendo sua pergunta: sim, no SOEN com ctz seria fechada. Agora te faço uma nova pergunta: E no [Software Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60887/software-recommendations), essa pergunta seria fechada?

Comment: Talvez sim, talvez não. Eu mesmo no Software Recommendations votaria para fechar, pelo mesmo motivo. Mas fica a pergunta no ar...